# Drag and Drop not working in android emulator.Is there anything to add to run it in emulator

Tags: html, cordova, android-emulator

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
 <html> <head>` <style type="text/css">
 #div1, #div2, #div3, #div4
{float:left; width:100px; height:35px; margin:10px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function allowDrop(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); }
] function drag(ev) { ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id); }
function drop(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text"); ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)); }
</script> </head> <body>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> <img src="http://creativebits.org/files/trash-osx.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31" /> </div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</body> </html>
```

I want drag and drop event in my application..... 
 I have written the above html5 file which i got from net,this is working fine in web browser but when i am running it on android emulator no function is working.no click option also coming...Should i need to add anything to run it on android emulator or on any other devices.....

Comment: What is it that's making you believe that [drag and drop should work on Android](http://caniuse.com/#search=drag)?